Autorizacion en el WS del SRI
Cuando envío un XML el WS de recepción en el ambiente de prueba del SRI, si me la recepta, pero a lo que hago la consulta de autorización no me muestra ningún error ni nada. Sera error de código o que error será? También estaba investigando si tenía algún problema en el SRI, pero estoy todo bien y me dijeron que no tengo ninguna restricción para facturar electrónicamente.
NOTA: El código está hecho con node.js y estoy usando SoapUI para las pruebas y la firma electrónica es de la empresa "Firmas electrónicas".
A lo que envío el xml de la factura ya firmada me devuelve este mensaje:


<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:validarComprobanteResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ec.gob.sri.ws.recepcion">
         <RespuestaRecepcionComprobante>
            <estado>RECIBIDA</estado>
            <comprobantes/>
         </RespuestaRecepcionComprobante>
      </ns2:validarComprobanteResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>



Pero a lo que envío a consultar la clave de acceso para la Autorizacion no me devuelve nada:
Proceso de envio:


soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ec="http://ec.gob.sri.ws.autorizacion">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ec:autorizacionComprobante>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <claveAccesoComprobante>0409202401172386782400110020010000001102775085117</claveAccesoComprobante>
      </ec:autorizacionComprobante>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>



Respuesta:


<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:autorizacionComprobanteResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ec.gob.sri.ws.autorizacion">
         <RespuestaAutorizacionComprobante>
            <claveAccesoConsultada>0409202401172386782400110020010000001102775085117</claveAccesoConsultada>
            <numeroComprobantes>0</numeroComprobantes>
            <autorizaciones/>
         </RespuestaAutorizacionComprobante>
      </ns2:autorizacionComprobanteResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>



A continuación, el código:


const getP12 = async (path) => {
      try {
        const RESPONSE = await fs.readFile(path);
        return RESPONSE;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`Error al cargar el archivo p12: ${error.message}`);
      }
    };

    const getXML = async (path) => {
      try {
        const RESPONSE = await fs.readFile(path);
        return RESPONSE.toString("utf8");
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`Error al cargar el XML: ${error.message}`);
      }
    };

    const sha1_base64 = (txt, encoding) => {
      let md = forge.md.sha1.create();
      md.update(txt, encoding);
      const HASH = md.digest().toHex();
      const BUFFER = new buffer.Buffer(HASH, "hex");
      const BASE64 = BUFFER.toString("base64");
      return BASE64;
    };

    const hexToBase64 = (hexStr) => {
      hexStr = hexStr.padStart(hexStr.length + (hexStr.length % 2), "0");
      const BYTES = hexStr.match(/.{2}/g).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16));
      return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...BYTES));
    };

    const bigIntToBase64 = (bigint) => {
      var base64 = "";
      base64 = btoa(
        bigint
          .toString(16)
          .match(/\w{2}/g)
          .map(function (a) {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));
          })
          .join("")
      );

      base64 = base64.match(/.{1,76}/g).join("\n");

      return base64;
    };

    const getRandomNumber = (min = 990, max = 999999) => {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    };

    const sign = async (p12Path, p12Password, xmlPath) => {
      const ARRAYBUFFER = await getP12(p12Path);
      let xml = await getXML(xmlPath);

      xml = xml.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
      xml = xml.replace(/(?<=\>)(\r?\n)|(\r?\n)(?=\<\/)/g, "").trim();
      xml = xml.replace(/(?<=\>)(\s*)/g, "");

      const ARRAYUINT8 = new Uint8Array(ARRAYBUFFER);
      const B64 = forge.util.binary.base64.encode(ARRAYUINT8);
      const DER = forge.util.decode64(B64);

      const ASN1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(DER);
      const p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(ASN1, p12Password);

      const PKCS8BAGS = p12.getBags({
        bagType: forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag,
      });

      const certbags = p12.getBags({
        bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag,
      });

      const cert = certbags[forge.oids.certBag][0].cert;

      let certificate;
      let pkcs8;
      let issuerName = "";

      const issuerAttrs = cert.issuer.attributes;

      issuerName = issuerAttrs
        .reverse()
        .map((attr) => {
          if (attr.shortName === undefined) {
            attr.shortName = "SERIALNUMBER";
          }
          return `${attr.shortName} = ${attr.value}`;
        })
        .join(", ");

      console.log(issuerName);

      pkcs8 = PKCS8BAGS[forge.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag][0];

      const notBefore = cert.validity["notBefore"];
      const notAfte = cert.validity["notAfter"];

      const currentDate = new Date();

      if (currentDate < notBefore || currentDate > notAfte) {
        throw new Error("Invalid certificate, certificate has expired");
      }

      const key = pkcs8.key ?? pkcs8.asn1;

      const certificateX509_pem = forge.pki.certificateToPem(cert);
      let certificateX509 = certificateX509_pem.substring(
        certificateX509_pem.indexOf("\n") + 1,
        certificateX509_pem.indexOf("\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
      );

      certificateX509 = certificateX509
        .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "")
        .replace(/([^\0]{76})/g, "$1\n");

      const certificateX509_asn1 = forge.pki.certificateToAsn1(cert);
      const certificateX509_der = forge.asn1.toDer(certificateX509_asn1).getBytes();
      const hash_certificateX509_der = sha1_base64(certificateX509_der);

      const certificateX509_serialNumber = parseInt(cert.serialNumber,16);

      const exponent = hexToBase64(key.e.data[0].toString(16));
      const modulus = bigIntToBase64(key.n);

      xml = xml.replace(/\t|\r/g, "");

      const sha1_xml = sha1_base64(
        xml.replace('version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"', ""),
        "utf8"
      );

      const namespaces =
        ' xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"';

      const Certificate_number = getRandomNumber();
      const Signature_number = getRandomNumber();
      const Signedproperties_number = getRandomNumber();
      const SignedInfo_number = getRandomNumber();
      const SignedPropertiesID_number = getRandomNumber();
      const Reference_ID_number = getRandomNumber();
      const SignatureValue_number = getRandomNumber();
      const Object_number = getRandomNumber();

      const isoDateTime = moment().format();

      let SignedProperties = "";
      SignedProperties +=
        '<etsi:SignedProperties Id="Signature' +
        Signature_number +
        "-SignedProperties" +
        Signedproperties_number +
        '">';

      SignedProperties += "<etsi:SignedSignatureProperties>";
      SignedProperties += "<etsi:SigningTime>";
      SignedProperties += isoDateTime;
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:SigningTime>";
      SignedProperties += "<etsi:SigningCertificate>";
      SignedProperties += "<etsi:Cert>";
      SignedProperties += "<etsi:CertDigest>";
      SignedProperties +=
        '<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1">';
      SignedProperties += "</ds:DigestMethod>";
      SignedProperties += "<ds:DigestValue>";
      SignedProperties += hash_certificateX509_der;
      SignedProperties += "</ds:DigestValue>";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:CertDigest>";
      SignedProperties += "<etsi:IssuerSerial>";
      SignedProperties += "<ds:X509IssuerName>";
      SignedProperties += issuerName;
      SignedProperties += "</ds:X509IssuerName>";
      SignedProperties += "<ds:X509SerialNumber>";
      SignedProperties += certificateX509_serialNumber;
      SignedProperties += "</ds:X509SerialNumber>";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:IssuerSerial>";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:Cert>";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:SigningCertificate>";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:SignedSignatureProperties>";

      SignedProperties += "<etsi:SignedDataObjectProperties>";
      SignedProperties +=
        '<etsi:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#Reference-ID-' +
        Reference_ID_number +
        '">';
      SignedProperties += "<etsi:Description>";
      SignedProperties += "contenido comprobante";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:Description>";
      SignedProperties += "<etsi:MimeType>";
      SignedProperties += "text/xml";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:MimeType>";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:DataObjectFormat>";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:SignedDataObjectProperties>";
      SignedProperties += "</etsi:SignedProperties>";

      const sha1_SignedProperties = sha1_base64(
        SignedProperties.replace(
          "<etsi:SignedProperties",
          "<etsi:SignedProperties " + namespaces
        )
      );

      let KeyInfo = "";
      KeyInfo += '<ds:KeyInfo Id="Certificate' + Certificate_number + '">';
      KeyInfo += "\n<ds:X509Data>";
      KeyInfo += "\n<ds:X509Certificate>\n";
      KeyInfo += certificateX509;
      KeyInfo += "\n</ds:X509Certificate>";
      KeyInfo += "\n</ds:X509Data>";
      KeyInfo += "\n<ds:KeyValue>";
      KeyInfo += "\n<ds:RSAKeyValue>";
      KeyInfo += "\n<ds:Modulus>\n";
      KeyInfo += modulus;
      KeyInfo += "\n</ds:Modulus>";
      KeyInfo += "\n<ds:Exponent>\n";
      KeyInfo += exponent;
      KeyInfo += "\n</ds:Exponent>";
      KeyInfo += "\n</ds:RSAKeyValue>";
      KeyInfo += "\n</ds:KeyValue>";
      KeyInfo += "\n</ds:KeyInfo>";

      const sha1_KeyInfo = sha1_base64(
        KeyInfo.replace("<ds:KeyInfo", "<ds:KeyInfo " + namespaces)
      );

      let SignedInfo = "";
      SignedInfo +=
        '<ds:SignedInfo Id="Signature-SignedInfo' + SignedInfo_number + '">';
      SignedInfo +=
        '\n<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315">';
      SignedInfo += "</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>";
      SignedInfo +=
        '\n<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1">';
      SignedInfo += "</ds:SignatureMethod>";
      SignedInfo +=
        '\n<ds:Reference Id="SignedPropertiesID' +
        SignedPropertiesID_number +
        '" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#Signature' +
        Signature_number +
        "-SignedProperties" +
        Signedproperties_number +
        '">';
      SignedInfo +=
        '\n<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sah1">';
      SignedInfo += "</ds:DigestMethod>";
      SignedInfo += "\n<ds:DigestValue>";
      SignedInfo += sha1_SignedProperties;
      SignedInfo += "</ds:DigestValue>";
      SignedInfo += "\n</ds:Reference>";
      SignedInfo += '\n<ds:Reference URI="#Certificate' + Certificate_number + '">';
      SignedInfo +=
        '\n<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1">';
      SignedInfo += "</ds:DigestMethod>";
      SignedInfo += "<ds:DigestValue>";
      SignedInfo += sha1_KeyInfo;
      SignedInfo += "</ds:DigestValue>";
      SignedInfo += "\n</ds:Reference>";
      SignedInfo +=
        '\n<ds:Reference Id="Reference-ID-' +
        Reference_ID_number +
        '" URI="#comprobante">';
      SignedInfo += "\n<ds:Transforms>";
      SignedInfo +=
        '\n<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature">';
      SignedInfo += "</ds:Transform>";
      SignedInfo += "\n</ds:Transforms>";
      SignedInfo +=
        '\n<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1">';
      SignedInfo += "</ds:DigestMethod>";
      SignedInfo += "\n<ds:DigestValue>";
      SignedInfo += sha1_xml;
      SignedInfo += "</ds:DigestValue>";
      SignedInfo += "\n</ds:Reference>";
      SignedInfo += "\n</ds:SignedInfo>";

      const canonizalized_SignedInfo = SignedInfo.replace(
        "ds:SignedInfo",
        "ds:SignedInfo " + namespaces
      );
      const md = forge.md.sha1.create();
      md.update(canonizalized_SignedInfo, "utf8");
      let signature = btoa(key.sign(md))
        .match(/.{1,76}/g)
        .join("\n");

      let xades_bes = "";
      xades_bes +=
        "<ds:Signature " + namespaces + ' Id="Signature' + Signature_number + '">';
      xades_bes += "\n" + SignedInfo;
      xades_bes +=
        '\n<ds:SignatureValue Id="SignatureValue' + SignatureValue_number + '">\n';
      xades_bes += signature;
      xades_bes += "\n</ds:SignatureValue>";
      xades_bes += "\n" + KeyInfo;
      xades_bes +=
        '\n<ds:Object Id="Signature' +
        Signature_number +
        "-Object" +
        Object_number +
        '">';
      xades_bes +=
        '<etsi:QualifyingProperties Target="#Signature' + Signature_number + '">';
      xades_bes += SignedProperties;
      xades_bes += "</etsi:QualifyingProperties>";
      xades_bes += "</ds:Object>";
      xades_bes += "</ds:Signature>";

      let signed = xml.replace(/(<[^<]+)$/, xades_bes + "$1");
      return signed
    };

    P12S.forEach((element) => {
      sign(
        "cert/" + element.filename,
        element.password,
        "comprobantes/generados/Factura_1723867824.xml"
      );
    });



Gracias de antemano.

Primero, en este escenario se me ocurren dos posibles causas:

Al enviar el b64 del comprobante, la clave de acceso enviada no es la clave de acceso consultada, lo cual termina en la situación descrita
Existe un error desconocido por el WS por lo que se requiere de un análisis profundo del XML generado, para eso lo que yo haría es validar con el XSD provisto por el SRI (que en teoría debería pasar de largo el error pero es mejor prevenir) y luego depurar con el proceso que compartió Jybaro Software House en este artículo

Segundo, un par de recomendaciones: 1. Simplificar el código no siempre lo hace más legible, hay partes que parecen haberse refactorizado sin tener el contexto del código completo (por ejemplo hay una variable que no se usa nunca), 2. El uso de momentjs no es recomendado ni por los mismos desarrolladores de momentjs, en la documentación ellos mismos lo aclaran e incluso adjuntan un artículo del 2020

Ya agregué el proceso que hago con el SoapUi

Saludos. Vi el artículo de Jybaro Software House y seguí los pasos para hacer la depuración, ósea comparé la firma que sale con el sistema de facturación del SRI con la firma que me sale a mí y es todo igual, certificado, modulo, etc. Ahora si me devuelve un mensaje como "NO AUTORIZADO" y el error es porque me sale "La firma es invalida [Firma inválida (firma y/o certificados alterados)" pero todo está igual a lo que sale en el sistema de facturación del SRI.
¡Será que podemos hacer una videollamada para mostrarte el código y ver si hay errores por favor! me ayudarías mucho

Bueno la llamada tendría costo como asesoría así que queda a tu deliberación. Lo que parece estar pasando es que el proceso de extracción de los certificados está fallando, en el caso del facturador Offline del SRI porque hay un select que te permite escoger la entidad de la firma y en el caso del código por la forma de extracción.

Claro, cuanto me cobrarías por una asesoría?
